# Convenient method to collect the original TTL values of DNS A records set by zone

Tags: dns, ttl, dig

To avoid the cached TTL values, the way I used to do is to collect the authoritative DNS servers of one domain and issue the queries directly to the ADNS servers by using the *@global-server* option of *dig*.

However, currently I need to process hundreds of millions of records so it is not a feasible solution. Is there any easy way to obtain the original TTL values set by the zone administrators?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

The authoritative name servers are the public source of that data, so any alternatives involve getting the information via non-DNS routes. You could, for example, ask the owner of a domain you're interested in for a copy of the zone file and read that.

Why on Earth do you want to see the TTL of hundreds of millions of records?